# Динамически создать и обработать элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста как можно динамически создавать и обрабатывать элементы?
   Например вот скрипт создания динамических ссылок

```
   success: function (data) {

                   var res = "";
                   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                       res += "Data " + data[i].Data + " "+ "<a id='"+i+"'"+"href=/api/admin/delete/"+data[i].ID+">Удалить</a>" + "<br />";
                   }
                   console.log(key);

                   $("#result").html(res);

               }
```

А как теперь обработать эти ссылки?

```
   $("??").click(
  function (e) {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
          ........
             });
```

Comment: `"<a class='linkClass' id='...`  `$(".linkClass").click(...`

Answer (score 1):

Создавать можно либо через вставку HTML-кода, либо созданием элементов и их вставка (`Node.appendChild`).

А обрабатывать можно двумя способами:

1. Добавлять обработчик после создания (вряд ли подходит для `HTML` вставки).
2. Делегирование: слушать события не элементов, а ближайшего предка. Там проверять на ком событие (`Event.target`) и вызывать обработчик для него.
   Это хороший способ, в большинстве подобных случаев используйте его.

**UPD:**
Пример делегирования:

```js
$(_ => {
  let root = $('#root'),
      inc  = 0;
  
  // Динамическая добавка записей
  $('#addEntry').on('click', e => {
    root.append(`<div>Запись №${inc++}</div>`);
  });
  
  // Второй аргумент - это CSS-путь обрабатываемых элементов
  root.on('click', 'div', function(e){
    console.info(`Это обработчик записи с номером ${this.innerHTML.replace(/\D+/g, '')}`);
  });
});
```

```css
#root div{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div><hr />
<input type='button' id='addEntry' value='Добавить запись' />
```

Comment: А можно пример делегирования?

Comment: @Nameless, UPD.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать метод jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [{Data: 'data', ID: 1}, {Data: 'data2', ID: 2}];
    var res = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        res += "<a class='delete' id='"+i+"'>Удалить</a>" + "<br />";
    }

    $("#result").html(res);

    /* ... */

    $('body').on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // отмена действия браузера по умолчанию
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        /* ... */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function xxx() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.info("Link number: " + $(this).attr("id"))
};

$("#add").click(function() {
  var res = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    res += "Data " + i + " " + "<a id='" + i + "' class='linkClass' href='http://google.com' >Удалить</a>" + "<br />";
  }
  $("#result").html(res);
  $(".linkClass").on("click", xxx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Click me for add new link</button>
<br>
<span id="result"></span>
```